# How to use a proof by contradiction in group theory!

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, discrete-mathematics

A group $G$  is said to be abelian-by-finite if it has a normal subgroup $H$ of finite index in $G$.
I want to prove the following statement: "If a group $G$ has property $\mathcal P$ then it is  abelian-by-finite", and I want to use the proof by contradiction.
Can I formulate it in this way: Suppose $G$ has property $\mathcal P$ and it is not abelian-by-finite, therefore it exists a normal subgroup $H$ which is not of finite index in $G$? Can I use this to prove this statement by contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

We want to prove $A \implies B$ where $A$ is "abelian-by-finite" and $B$ is property $P$.  To prove this by contradiction you could assume $A$ and $\neg B$ and derive a contradiction.  Or you could prove the contrapositive $\neg B \implies \neg A$, which is equivalent.  Either way, assuming $B$, that $G$ has property $P$, will not help you as it is the thing you are trying to prove.

Comment: But considering this: $\neg(\exists x \in A, P(x)) \iff \forall x \in A, \neg P(x)$

Comment: and if we take $x \in A$ to be there exists a normal subgroup of $G$, and $P(x)$ that the subgroup is of finite index, can we equivalently say that for any subgroup of $G$ that is normal, that subgroup is not of finite index in $G$.

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove the implication
$$
 \text{$G$ has property $\mathcal{P}$}
 \implies
 \text{$G$ is abelian-by-finite},
$$
If you want to do a proof by contradiction you have to assume that $G$ has property $\mathcal{P}$ (i.e. that the left hand side holds) but that $G$ is not abelian-by-finite (i.e. that the right hand side does not hold).

Imagine  it like this: If you want to prove the implication
$$
 \text{it rains} \implies \text{the street gets wet}
$$
by contradiction then you assume that it rains, but that the street stays dry, and show that this leads to a contradiction.

---

Regarding your formulation: The converse of $G$ being abelian-by-finite is that $G$ has no normal subgroup of finite index, which is *not* equivalent to $G$ having a normal subgroup of infinite index (every infinite group has a normal subgroup of infinite index, namely the trivial subgroup, but an infinite group can still be abelian-by-finite). Instead it is equivalent to *every* normal subgroup of $G$ having infinite index.

(In your definition of abelian-at-finite you probably want to exclude $G$ itself as a normal subgroup, unless you want every group to be abelian-at-finite.)

Comment: But considering this: ¬(∃x∈A,P(x))⟺∀x∈A,¬P(x)    
     
and if we take x∈A to be there exists a normal subgroup of $G$, and$ P(x)$ that the subgroup is of finite index, can we equivalently say that for any subgroup of $G$ that is normal, that subgroup is not of finite index in $G$

Comment: This formulation is right. To compare it with your original statement: Here you say that _every_ normal subgroup of $G$ has infinite index. In your original post you say that there _exists_ a normal subgroup of infinite index.

Comment: So can I say that for any normal subgroup of $G$ has an infinite index in $G$, and then take an arbitrary normal  subgroup of $G$ that has an infinite index and if I get a contradiction, can then I conclude that the statement is true?

Comment: Then you could conclude that that the implication does indeed hold. But (depending on what $\mathcal{P}$ is) you probably have to use that _every_ proper normal subgroup has infinite index. If you just pick _one_ normal subgroup of infinite index and already get a contradiction out of the existence of this group, then you would have shown that _every_ normal subgroup of $G$ has infinite index, which is a stronger statement then abelian-at-finite.

Answer (score 0):

It was already said that having an infinite normal sub Group dos not mean that there is not a finite one. I wanted to elaborate on that with an example:
Consider A = the Boolean Group(also filed) under addition(tats 1,0 where 1+1=0).
And B = the Group of 2*2 matrix's under R.

Now let us look at A*B. This new Group(of Pairs) have an infinite normal subgroup:

{(1,a*I) | a in R} for example.

but it also have a finite normal Group:

{(a,0) | a in A}

(I promise that today I will learn how to use mathematical notations..)

Answer (score 0):

> Can I formulate it in this way: Suppose $G$ has property $\mathcal P$ and it is not abelian-by-finite, therefore it exists a normal subgroup $H$ which is not of finite index in $G$?

No.

The statement you're trying to negate is "$G$ has a normal subgroup $H$ of finite index in $G$."

That means **there exists** such a subgroup $H$.

The **negation** of $$\text{“There exists a group } H \text{ such that } \varphi(H)\text{''}$$ is $$\text{“For every group } H \text{ not } \varphi(H).\text{''}$$

The **negation** of
$$
\text{“There exists a subgroup } H \text{ of } G \text{ such that } H \text{ has finite index in } G \text{''}
$$
is
$$
\text{“Every subgroup } H \text{ of } G \text{ has infinite index in } G. \text{''}
$$
**Every** subgroup, not just one subgroup.

Comment: I am just trying to get it correctly! So if I take any subgroup( which is one of every subgroup) and get a contradiction, I still cant show that the initial implication is true?

Comment: You may use the full strength of the statement that it's EVERY subgroup $H$.  Suppose you say "Let $H$ be a subgroup.  Then by our assumption, $H$ has infinite index in $G$." and go on from there, then you're really only proving something you could have proved if you had just one subgroup with infinite index, so that's not using the full strength of the statement that it's _every_ subgroup.  However, without knowing what "property $\mathcal P$" is, I don't think I can tell you any more than that about how to proceed. $\qquad$

Comment: @ Michael Hardy: $\mathcal P$ means semigroup $S$ is permutable.

Comment: @ Michael Hardy: Property $\mathcal P$ means "semigroup $S$ is permutable.